# Is there a way for me to get all the string and convert it into a double and add all of them?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kua0A.png)

I am still new atFirebase and I wanted to ask in this image [Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLLf7.png) in the blue line. How do I turn them into a double and finally add all the blue line. Basically, I wanted to add all the price and place it on a text view for the total price.` Can someone help me this is the code I have done so far?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);


    mRecyclerView2 = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview3);
    mRecyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mModel2 = new ArrayList<>();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String userID = user.getUid();
    mAdapter2 = new ViewHolder2(Payment.this, mModel2);
    mRecyclerView2.setAdapter(mAdapter2);
    mDatabaseReference2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(userID).child("Ordered");
    mDatabaseReference2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            double cost = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Model2 model2 = postSnapshot.child("price").getValue(Model2.class);
                String venueLatString = String.valueOf(model2);
                double total = Double.parseDouble(venueLatString);

                cost = total + cost;
                String finaltotal = String.valueOf(cost);
                Total = findViewById(R.id.totalprice);
                Total.setText(finaltotal);

                mModel2.add(model2);
            }
            mAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

If I run the code it crashes. Please help.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have post the picture of error above

Comment: I see now, I'll write you an answer right away.

Comment: Thank you. I've been doing this problem for 2 days and I still have no answer.

Comment: Please check my answer below and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are using the following line of code in wrong way:

```
Model2 model2 = postSnapshot.child("price").getValue(Model2.class);
```

The child `price` holds a String and **not** a `Model2` object, so that's why that error.

To solve this, please remove from the above line of code, the call to `.child("price")`:

```
Model2 model2 = postSnapshot.getValue(Model2.class);
```

Now, to get the price as a double, please use the following lines of code:

```
String stringValue = model2.getPrice();
double price = Double.parseDouble(stringValue);
```

Having your `price` as a `double`, you can perform now any operation you need with it.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are the best! I'm really thankful for you!

Answer (score 0):

you can custom your    model like this

```
public class test {
    String food;
    String order;
    String price;

    public test() {
    }

    public test(String food, String order, String price) {
        this.food = food;
        this.order = order;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public void setFood(String food) {
        this.food = food;
    }

    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        double value = 0;
        try{
            value = Double.parseDouble(price);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            value = 0;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

now you can use **getPrice** to get your double value Directly

and in your adapter

```
            Test model2 = postSnapshot.getValue(Test.class);
```

and get your double value

model2.getPrice

Comment: Oh okay. I'll try it

Comment: How I can I use the to set text in the adapter cause Im getting an error in this part imageViewHolder.Cost.setText(mModelcur.getPrice());

Comment: setText must be String  not  double 
you can use   Cost.setText(String.valueof(mModelcur.getPrice()));